# Web Service JAX RS JWT JJWT o Auth0

Tags: java, webservice, rest, autenticación

Deseo utilizar alguna librería para implementar `jwt`. He probado algunas pero tengo problemas con jersey que no reconoce las librerías. Seguí algunos consejos en Stack, pero no termino de entender como se manejan los filtros con jersey y demás.

¿No se puede simplemente crear un token y agregarlo a la cabecera de respuesta?

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response authenticateUser(@FormParam("username") String username, 
                               @FormParam("password") String password) {
try {
// Authenticate the user using the credentials provided
// authenticate(username, password);
// Issue a token for the user
String compactJws = Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "pepe").compact();

   // Return the token on the response
   return Response.ok(compactJws).build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }      
}
```

En el trozo de código que copié utilicé jjwt, eso me da un error de classnotfound pero las librerías están importadas sin problemas..

con Auth0.jwt no tuve problemas y crea el token y lo envía en la respuesta. Suponiendo que eso esté bien, ¿debo en cada método chequear si el token es válido? Creo que la idea de los filtros es para no hacer esto, pero no logro entenderlo.

Estas son las dos consultas que estuve siguiendo.

[Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey)

[autorización](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766673/custom-jax-rs-authorization-using-jwt-in-each-request)

Comment: No se entiende que es lo que quieres hacer. Dices que quieres usar jwt ¿Cual es el objetivo o motivación para usarlo? ¿Que quieres hacer con jwt?¿Quieres hacer un WebServices?

Comment: Si, estoy haciendo un webservices, y necesito que los usuarios se logueen para acceder a los recursos, estoy utilizando filtros de jersey, y jwt para enviar un token después de que el usuario entregue sus credenciales.

Comment: Bueno yo uso resteasy y no tengo ningun problema aunque no uso autenticación, no se si quieras ver el código

Comment: Es que es lo que necesito, sino tendría que hacer el login en cada endpoints